# Помогите решить задачу на языке Python

Tags: python

Сколько существует различных трёхзначных чисел, записанных в четверичной системе счисления, в записи которых сумма первой и последней цифры строго больше цифры стоящей по середине?

Мой код:

```
a = "0123"
c = 0
for l1 in a:
  for l2 in a:
    for l3 in a:
          w = l1 + l2 + l3
          if w[0] + w[2] >= w[1] and w[0] != "0":
            c += 1
print(c)
```

Правильный ответ: 38. Но у меня выводит 36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем же мучаться с символами, если можно сразу оперировать числами?

```
a = {0,1,2,3}
c = 0
for l1 in {1,2,3}:
  for l2 in a:
    for l3 in a:
      if l1 + l2 > l3:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

И от проверки на 0 тоже можно отказаться, просто если не включать его в набор для итерации.

Альтернативный вариант от @АлексейР:

```
a = 0,1,2,3
c = 0
for l1 in a[1:]:
  for l2 in a:
    for l3 in a:
      if l1 + l2 > l3:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Альтернативный вариант от @StanislavVolodarskiy:

```
c = 0
for l1 in range(1,4):
  for l2 in range(4):
    for l3 in range(4):
      if l1 + l2 > l3:
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но можно немного оптимизировать. Множества излишни, достаточно кортежа или списка. Например, `а = 0,1,2,3`. В первом цикле `for l1 in a[1:]:`. А условие `if l1 + l2 > l3:`, скорее всего, д.б. `if l1 + l3 > l2:`, т.к. посередине l2

Comment: @АлексейР спасибо за комментарий. На счёт последнего утверждения - разницы между l2 и l3 для данного алгоритма нет. Если написали l1 + l2 > l3, то l2 - крайняя цифра, а l3 - средняя. Главное, чтобы первая цифра числа (l1) не была нулём.

Comment: `range(1, 4)`, `range(4)`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь

```
if w[0] + w[2] >= w[1]
```

вы складываете цифры как символы, так что в левой части получается строка из двух символов.

Вероятно, вы хотели этого (заметьте также "строго больше"):

```
if int(w[0]) + int(w[2]) > int(w[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решал это задание так:

```
import itertools


# Функция проверки
def check(x):
    # число не может начинаться с нуля
    if x[0] == "0":
        return False
    # инвертируем условие, если число
    # посередине больше или равно сумме боковых
    if int(x[0]) + int(x[-1]) <= int(x[1]):
        return False
    # если число удовлетворяет всем требованиям
    return True


k = set()  # множество уникальных значений
# Проходимся по всем вариантам (000, 001 ... 333)
for i in itertools.product('0123', repeat=3):
    a = ''.join(i)  # product возвращает тип tuple, конвертируем в строку
    # если число удовлетворяет всем условиям, то
    # добавляем в множество
    if check(a):
        k.add(a)

print(len(k), k)
```

Comment: Вот человек, который хорошо объясняет это задание, да и вообще информатику: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFg1xyvNO28